# Install KDE Development Environment

Tags: 16.04, kde, c++

I got project that contains file with extension `.kdevprj`. I found 
 this is `KDE Development Environment` project. How I can install this IDE and open my project?

Answer (score 2):

Install kdevelop

```
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

or, depending on your version of Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install kdevelop
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdevelop

If needed the kdevelop documentation is here:

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-kdevelop/kdevelop/index.html

https://www.kdevelop.org/features